# Proving a unique solution with the norm of a matrix in a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

Let $B\in\mathcal{M}_n$ with $\left \| B \right \|<1$ and $c$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that the linear system:

$u=Bu+c$

Has a unique solution $u$

I know how to prove a unique solution, but I don't know how to use the norm of the matrix to prove it.

Comment: $\|B\|<1$ implies that $I-B$ is invertible.

Comment: @Kavi I'm sorry that I'm clueless. How that can imply that $I-B$ is invertible?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Kavi Rama Murthy's comment: the eigenvalues of $I-B$ are of the form $1-\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. If $\|B\| < 1$, then $|\lambda| < 1$ for all eigenvalues of $B$. This implies $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $I-B$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know the question is very basic, but now I get it!